# Split character string into unequal segments R

Tags: r

I have some data that is I need to split into multiple elements, but there is not a specific identifier within the row to split on. I know the positions of different variables; is there a way I can split the string into multiple uneven parts based on my prior information. Example:

String: `" 00008         L           1957110642706          194711071019561030R 1/812.5000000"`

Desired result:

```
" 00008 ","        ","L","       ","    ","19571106","42706","          ","19471107","10","19561030","R 1/8","12.5000000"
```

So, my prior information is that the first element begins on the first position and is seven spaces long; the second begins at the 8th position in the string and is 8 spaces long; the 3rd element starts at the 16th position and is 1 space long, etc, etc.

Comment: Did you look at `read.fwf` from base R of `read_fwf` from the `readr` package?

Comment: You need to `dput()` your data as part of the MCVE requirement for questions in the `r` tag. Please hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: @Hack-R what do I need to `dput`? I've asked many a question without doing that, I believe I provided enough sample data here.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus No I haven't! Looks v promising though so I am checking it out.

Comment: I agree that this is enough information.

Answer (score 1):

```
xstr <- " 00008         L           1957110642706          194711071019561030R 1/812.5000000"
```

Rather than use this description:

> first element begins on the first position and is seven spaces long; the second begins at the 8th position in the string and is 8 spaces long; the 3rd element starts at the 16th position and is 1 space long, etc, etc. ...

I'm just going to take the desired widths from your specified answer (`nchar(res)`):

```
res <- c(" 00008 ","        ","L","       ","    ","19571106","42706","          ","19471107","10","19561030","R 1/8","12.5000000")
```

Make sure that all variables are read as character strings:

```
res2 <- read.fwf(textConnection(xstr),widths=nchar(res),
         colClasses=rep("character",length(res)))
```

Test:

```
all.equal(unname(unlist(res2)),res)  ## TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple `substr` function over your array of read lines:

```
my_lines <- read.table("your_file") #Or whatever way you read the lines

firstColumn <- substr(my_lines,1,7) #you can also use as.numeric and others if needed
secondColumn <- substr(my_lines,8,11)
# ..etc
rm(my_lines) #to save memory
```

Sometimes this is actually faster than other read.something packages specially if you dont use them correctly.